# How to set Image size for Improving OCR output.?

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I am working information reading from MRZ(Machine Readable Zone) image  using Tesseract Library.I had tried some [google images](https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&q=republique%20francaise%20carte%20nationale%20d%27identite&revid=17833319&ei=LFAJVMitHILIuASvsILACA&ved=0CCAQsiU) and I got good results.But when I went to real time images,that is when images are captured from iphone camera, I did not get good result.

**Got good results for the below google image**

[image]

**Image size of the above image**

It is google image.Size is 543x83.

**OCR performs poor when I took image from iphone**

[image]

**Above image details.**

Image captured from Iphone.Image size 2205x268

1.How to get good results for the above realtime image.?

2.Is there any recommended image size needed for Tesseract OCR?

Answer (score 2):

I have used ImageMagick for this kind of thing with some success - it is free and available for OSX, Windows and Linux from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org). It is very hard to find general purpose parameters and this took a fair amount of fiddling around:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Enhance image as much as possible for Tesseract OCR
convert input.jpg -normalize  \( -clone 0 -colorspace gray -negate -lat 50x50+10% -contrast-stretch 0 -blur 1x65535 -level 50x100% \) -compose copy_opacity -composite -opaque none -background white -adaptive-blur 3 out.jpg

# OCR the image and cat the results
tesseract out.jpg p && cat p.txt
```

**OCR'ed Text Output:**

```
IDFRADOUEL<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<932013
U506932020438CHRISTIANE<<NI2906209F3
```

And this is the image, as prepared by the above command for OCR:

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this? You are very quiet.

Comment: Without Imagemagick,how to get above output using opencv or any other pre processing steps.?